# JNDI datasource fails in Spring for Transactional & Eclipselink

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

We are using Eclipselink and I want to enable in Spring the TransactionsalManagement via annoation. Therefore I have a class like:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
...
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        final EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource()); // point of FAILURE
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // This uses JNDI, you could create the data source in any way you want
        try {
            final InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
            final Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            return (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myDS");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to lookup datasource", e);
        }
    }
```

and in the `servlet.xml`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDS"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" resource-ref="true" />
```

and in the `context.xml` it says

```
<Resource
    global="jdbc/myDS"
    name="jdbc/myDS"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

with this configuration I get always an exception for ClassCast, i.e.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ceb3620f cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
```

and have no real clue how to resolve the issue in sense of shifting the TransactionManagement to Spring.

Bottom line: I want to enable the Transactionmanagement for Spring with EclipseLink whereas my db-access-config is loacted in `META-INF/context.xml`. Could somebody give me a hint how to configure it properly?

Comment: Why do you have a `@Bean` and XML definition for your datasource. Use one or the other, don't try to do both.

Comment: Major reason is that the current project relies heavily on the XML config - and enabling Springs transactional handling would be a next step. Anyway solutions available?

Comment: There isn't because you have 2 beans, 1 overriding the other, with non-matching types. That simply isn't going to work, either remove 1 of the options or fix the return type. Also not sure why you want Java Config as what you want is perfectly doable through XML.

Comment: you mean by _doable through XML_ that I should configure it via `context.xml`. I did some research on the internet but getting more confused. Most of the samples are based on hibernate - do not know if they apply to EclipseLink. Plus also do not know wiich of the `transactionManager` I should take (`jdbc`, `orm`)? Is there a full working example around with the xml-config?

Comment: Java or XML the classes to use are the same, there is no difference. The only difference is that instead of `@EnableTransactionManagement` you need to use `<tx:annotation-driven >`.